# Remove fields from typescript interface object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am getting a json response and storing it in mongodb, however the fields that I don't need are also getting in to the database, is there anyway to strip the uneseccary fields?

```
interface Test{
    name:string
};
const temp :Test = JSON.parse('{ "name":"someName","age":20 }') as Test;
console.log(temp);
```

output :

```
{ name: 'someName', age: 20 }
```

Comment: I believe you need to create a new object which doesn't have the unwanted properties and cast your current object to that. It is better if you inherit both interface from the same interface.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a function that picks certain properties from a given object:

```
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
    const copy = {} as Pick<T, K>;

    keys.forEach(key => copy[key] = obj[key]);

    return copy;
}
```

Then:

```
let obj = { "name": "someName", "age": 20 };
let copy = pick(obj, "name") as Test;
console.log(copy); // { name: "someName" }
```

Comment: I have found a npm package ts-transformer-keys we could specify the keys automatically with your function

Comment: Have you looked at [the source](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys/blob/master/transformer.ts)? It actually opens up the ts file at runtime with the ts compiler api to get the keys in your object. It sounds like an extreme overkill, I wouldn't use it

Answer (score 4):

Let say you have this object.

```
const x = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
```

If you want to make a object with only `a` and `b`, you can use the following method.

```
const {c, ...y} = x;
console.log(y);
```

You will see that `y` has only `a` and `b` now. 
Also this will not give an error if the field `c` was not in `x`. As an example,

```
const x: any = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
const {d, ...y} = x;
console.log(y);
```

This works perfectly fine without any error and if you log the value of `d`, it will be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to remove age

```
temp = {...temp, age: undefined}
```

This will remove `age` from your object for good.

Comment: What if there are a lot fields which I don't want it to be there?

Comment: Understood instead I have to manually choose the fields which I want, I have around 30 fields and I need around 10

Comment: Yes, this is fast if you have few keys to remove. The chosen answer is good, do not use `delete`! It's SLOW!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a strongly-typed way, you can define a dummy/ideal object which satisfies your interface (`const dummy: IMyInterface = {someField: "someVal"};`), and then filter incoming objects' fields against `Object.keys(dummy)`. This way your compiler will complain if you update the interface without updating this 'filtering' code.