# Typescript - How to cast object to interface

Tags: typescript

Suppose there is an interface

```
interface A {
  a: number;
}
```

and currently I have a raw object

```
const a = { a: 1, b: '2' };
```

I expect a way to get `x` to be `{ a: 1 }`, which contains only members defined in interface.

This can be achieved through creating an empty `{}` and looping over and filling in all `A`'s members, but considering interface members and object's redundant fields can be up to dozens, it is not practical to do so.

I tried

```
let x = <A> a; // or let x = a as A;
console.log((x as any).b); // still exist
```

I also looked up in `lodash` and found `keys` and `pick`, but these are targeted for class instance instead of interface.

Comment: This is not "casting", which doesn't even exist in TS. It's "picking".

Comment: @Mike it's not clear what you want to achieve. **ts** duck typing let  downcast the type of `a` to `A` and with typescript editors you can access only to members of `A` but the real object is always of type `a`. Because **ts** type erasure implies that objects are of type `Object` at runtime you see the whole `a`. If you want __another__ object you have to copy its properties (like pick solution suggests). Instead if you want a compile time check use `A` and don't worry about what the real object is.

Comment: @Aris2World I have an interface definition and would like to convert an object with redundant fields to it. In addition, I do not want to explicitly state the fields to pick.

Comment: @Mike maybe there is a misconception about object and type (what an interface represent). Suppose you have also this `interface B { b: string; }`. You can treat the object `a` as an object of type both `A` and `B`: `let x: A = a` you can access members of `A` or  `let x: B = a` you can access members of `B`. The object `a` is of type Object which is the only one  existing in javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Interfaces don't exist at runtime. Your best option would be delete unwanted properties yourself or create a copy of the object with the properties you need.

For example you can use a method like this (method copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44203348/2419531)):

```
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
    const copy = {} as Pick<T, K>;

    keys.forEach(key => copy[key] = obj[key]);

    return copy;
}

const a = { a: 1, b: '2' };
let copy : A = pick(a, "a");
console.log(copy);
```

Comment: Good. Add only that if he wants to have a variable of type `A` he can write `let x: A = pick(a, "a")`

Comment: how can i provide ```"a"```? can i get it from definition of interface?

Comment: @Mike No. It has to be from a value present after compilation. If you want to get the keys of an interface, you can take a look at [this library](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys) suggested by Amid. But looking at the source code of that library (it reads the syntax tree of the program), it might be a bit too much.

Answer (score 2):

Basically your question boils down to the problem of getting all properties of the interface as an array of strings and then make an copy of the object containing only those properties. Making a copy of object is pretty simple and there are tons of examples out there. But the first issue is much harder to tackle.

As far as I know the only way to get this done "now" is to use custom transformers for typescript during compilation. Here is an [example](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys), but please note - this require to use typescript 2.4+ that is not yet in stable release.