# how can I modify http response to a interface?

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular8

I have an interface:

```
export interface Device {
  id: string;
  name: string
}
```

and I mock http response with extra data:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Device } from './device.model';
import { Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';
const devices = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'device1',
    serial: 'fdfd'

  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'device2',
    serial: 'fdfd'
  },
];
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DevicesDataService {

  constructor() { }
  getDevices(): Observable<Array<Device>> {
    return timer(200).pipe(mapTo(devices));
  }
}
```

The problem is, what returns is the response with the 3 fields.

How can I return a response that match the interface, so the `Observable<Array<Device>>` will contain only 2 fields?

I want to call the `getDevices()` method and get observable with array of device objects with id,name fields only.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203045/remove-fields-from-typescript-interface-object

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/pluck.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to it manually i afraid.

```
getDevices(): Observable<Array<Device>> {
    return timer(200).pipe(mapTo(devices),
    map(arr=>arr.map(({name,id})=>({name,id})));
  }
```

Comment: its not working for me , i get error      error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{ name: any;
id: any; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Device[]>'.

Comment: What did result do u see

Comment: i not have any result i just copy paste your code , saved and got this error

Comment: ERROR in apps/marketplace/src/app/devices/state/devices-data.service.ts(25,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{ name: any;
id: any; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Device[]>'.
      Type '{ name: any; id: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Device[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

Comment: apps/marketplace/src/app/devices/state/devices-data.service.ts(25,51): error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ id: string; name: string; serial: string; }[]'.
    apps/marketplace/src/app/devices/state/devices-data.service.ts(25,57): error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ id: string; name: string; serial: string; }[]'.